# How to switch pointer to next column in csv module of python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am writing data from xls file column by column. Now i want to write that data in csv same as column by column.

Problem is i am not getting how to switch the pointer to next column.
Currently i am getting O/P as below from my code:

```
abc
pqr
,
def
ghi
```

What i want is

```
abc,def
pqr,ghi
```

My sample code:

```
 for k in col1,col2:
    for i in range(2,10):
        test = (sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value)
        c.writerow([test])
    c.writerow(",")  #switch to next column.. Not working
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing the row out on every element, you should probably put each column element into a list, cast it as a tuple (because that's what writerow expects, and write the entire row out at once.

You are also using rows on the inner loop, where you should likely be using columns.  The way you had it you were going down each row then column, when it should be the other way around.  Like reading a book, you tackle each word individually (column item in inner loop) and you move down to the next line (row item in outer loop) when you are done with the current line.

```
# Rows 2-9
for i in range(2,10): 
    row = []
    for k in col1,col2:
        row.append(unicode(sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value))

    c.writerow(tuple(row))  #switch to next column.. Not working
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But the problem is the value that "sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value" is not in string. I tried it to convert it into string but it didn't work. After every char i am getting comma

Comment: temp = str(test);  row.append(temp). But i am getting this as O/P

Comment: 1,4,2,1,2,2,6,",",1,4,2,3,2,4,6,",",1,4,2,3,2,4,7,",",1,4,2,3,2,4,8,",",1,4,2,3,2,4,9,",",1,4,2,3,2,7,3,",",1,4,2,3,2,7,4,",",1,4,2,3,2,7,5
W,0,6,-,1,",",W,0,6,-,2,",",W,0,6,-,3,",",W,0,6,-,4,",",W,0,6,-,5,",",W,0,6,-,6,",",W,0,6,-,7,",",W,0,6,-,8

Comment: What is the output from the first print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value)

Comment: From the first print this is the O/P "1421226".. Some no basically.. Which i was trying to convert in string but thats not working

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize writerow expects a tuple, so you can cast you list as a tuple to get rid of all the extra commas.  You also don't need the ','.join(row). https://pymotw.com/2/csv/

Comment: Also I bet if you print(type(sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value)) you will get <type 'str'> which means that even though you are printing numbers python is treating the value as a string, so conversion isn't a problem for you.  Convert the list to a tuple and you will likely get what you want.

Comment: It's type is long  "1421226"
<type 'long'> and for 2nd column type is unicode "W06-1"
<type 'unicode'>... tried tuple but didn't work

Comment: Ohh got the reason of comma after every char. I think its because of syntax of writerow. So, now i have used c.writerow([row_str]) i.e putting row_str in [ ] brackets. Now the O/P is 1421226;1423246;1423247;1423248;1423249;1423273;1423274;1423275
W06-1;W06-2;W06-3;W06-4;W06-5;W06-6;W06-7;W06-8

Comment: Thanks for the info, you don't want to convert unicode to str as that typically means hoping there's an ASCII equivalent for each symbol.  You should cast all values to unicode, you will have a list of unicode items, and you can make that a tuple.  My answer will reflect the suggestion.

Comment: Ohh sry,   i didn't check your tuple syntax c.writerow(tuple(row))... that also works perfectly fine.. Thanks

Comment: Also, looks like your output is row1col1;row2col1;row3col1...  If you switch the inner and outer loop like in my code you should get row1col1, row1col2;row2col1,row2col2;row3col1row2col2... If that's how you need your csv

Comment: Now, the only problem is both column O/P is coming in 2 rows not in 2 columns. Current O/P is : 1421226,1423246,1423247,1423248,1423249,1423273,1423274,1423275
W06-1,W06-2,W06-3,W06-4,W06-5,W06-6,W06-7,W06-8...Expected O/P is: 1421226, W06-1 same 2nd 2 rows on 2nd line

Comment: Nice!  Please read the inner/outer loop changes I suggested in the answer and previous comment.

Comment: From your output it looks like it's getting column 2, but only after going through every row in column 1.  This seems to be because the inner loop in your question code iterates over the rows.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you worked it out!  Please consider accepting my solution if it is correct or let me know where I am incorrect.